# What is this TRRS jack which appears longer than the standard jack?

Tags: usb, audio, cable, 3.5mm

I recently purchased an USB thermometer. The USB device has a 3.5mm connector to receive the corresponding cable which has a 3.5mm jack on one end, and an actual temperature sensor on the other end.

The cable is too short for my specific needs, so I want to use an extension cable. An USB extension cable is not very practical in my case, so I wanted to use the 3.5mm extension cable instead.

To my surprise, the thermometer uses a TRRS jack I've never seen before. This is a comparison between (1) the jack used by the thermometer and (2) an ordinary 3.5mm (non-TRRS) jack:

[image]

The TRRS jack has an additional connector, but this one is also a few millimeters longer. When plugged to the USB device, there is no gap between the device and the black plastic part of the connector.

Comparisons between different plugs are very explicit: standard four-conductor and three-conductor plugs have the same size (also notice the narrow sleeve, compared to the first photo).

[image]

This means that I won't be able to use an extension cable such as [this one](http://amzn.com/B01552UGKG).

What is the type of the plug used by the thermometer? Are there extension cables for that?

Comment: [Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks](http://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/)

Comment: If, as it appears, the TRSS jack is non-standard, then the easiest way to extend the cable would be to buy a USB extension cable.

Comment: USB needs at least 4 connections to work. Yes they do sell 4 conductor 3.5mm extensions...http://www.amazon.com/YCS-Basics-3-5mm-female-conductor/dp/B00LMNQUF8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this has been eating away at you for the past nearly 8 years, I've just come across the answer:

#### The longer 3.5mm jack is the UK standard, whereas the shorter jack is the US standard.

I discovered this when ordering a panel-mount female jack for a project, and upon finding that my male headphone jack didn't reach the last contact, read the datasheet and found that the female jack was UK standard. The male UK jacks are about 19mm in length, whereas the male US jacks are about 14mm in length.